# Java applet taking a screenshot of browser with a flash application, flash missing

Tags: java, javascript, html, flash, overlay

I am attempting to create a Java applet that takes a screenshot of the browser containing a flash application. The case for that is to have a "Bug found/Feedback" sidebar for the testers of our flash application that can send a form with a screenshot of the tester's browser with his actual view so that the developers can understand the comment/bug.

I am using the `Robot().createScreenCapture(Rectangle)` method and I indeed get the screenshot but the flash application is missing from the image file created. I was fearing that because I had guessed that Flash was using overlay and direct access to the graphical driver.

My question is: is there a way to get the actual screen viewed by the user with the Robot class ? If not, is there another way to do that via Java ? And finally, if not, what would be an alternative to achieve the same conclusion which is to take a screenshot of the tester's screen that can be send via HTML/JavaScript to our servers.

Important: 
- It must be a browser based solution.
- It *"must"* be browser and OS independent (that would be a PLUS, but if it's only for windows, that would be okay in last resort)
- I have read about the `Robot()` methods to simulate a (Alt)PrintScreen keyboard action and take the content of the clipboard but it's too dependent of the Browser/OS.
- I understand that there are permissions issues to access the screen but that's something that we can tell to the testers.

Thanks in advance to the repliers,

O.

Comment: I highly doubt the browser sandbox would provide any api for a component to snapshot information beyond its own content.  Certainly this would not be something Flash could do, or privacy violation could be all over places.

Comment: That's something I know. That's why I was using Java with permissions to the Robot() methods. There's a way to render the webpage with a javascript library to create a "screenshot" but we need the client side image with the flash application. The testers will log feedbacks but also bugs where the flash will crash so we cannot get the screen from flash. When I say "browser based", I mean any app that can be run into a browser, like a java applet.